# Getting JSON response with 400 bad request in Angular 2

Tags: angular, magento, angular-routing, angular-services

Im trying to call REST API of Magento 2 from Angular 2.

Facing this issue from very long and really need a fix on the same or atleast suggestion on where the issue is?

Below is how im calling REST from Angualar:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
public _productUrl = 'http://10..../Mage_ang2/index.php/rest/V1/customers/1';

constructor(private _http: Http) { }

getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8' });
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ntthnrbj1uam2tuv1ekva7n8jh18mcnkby3');
let options = new RequestOptions( {method: RequestMethod.Get, headers: headers });


console.log(headers);
    return this._http.get(this._productUrl,options)
        .map((response: Response) => <IProduct[]> response.json())
        .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

When i post the same in Postman, i get a response.

When i run through Angular2, with same headers, I get a JSON response but with 400 (Bad Request) !

Also the response doesnt come to actual request call.

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the console in browser says??

Comment: I have attached the screenshot for the browser console, which says 400 but i get a json data

Comment: Have updated the error which im getting in broswer console @Aravind...Have done enough search on this refetch and CORS issue, Need help on identifying where the issue is?

Comment: Any suggestions @aravind?

Comment: nope. not enough information. seems like server side issue.

Comment: What other information u require?

Answer (score 1):

I have been using same syntax in my sample application but without authorization header. Everything seems correct.

The issue may with setting authorization header. Check the authorization token for correctness.

Try this syntax for setting headers

```
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8';Authorization: **token** });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should work

```
 let headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization':'Bearer ntthnrbj1uam2tuv1ekva7n8jh18mcnkby3'
    });

 return this._http.get(url,{headers:headers})
        .map(response: any => {
            return response.json();
        });
```

Comment: Could you please tell what is the change in ur code and mine!! and where are you using get ()??

Comment: @Sach right, there is `get()`. You can see the diff by comparing  the request Headers. I have not tried

Comment: @Sach Can you compare the request header of postman and angular?

Comment: Exactly the same headers, using the same content type and Auth Bearer key values..!!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'Bearer ntthnrbj1uam2tuv1ekva7n8jh18mcnkby3' });    

let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this._http.get(this._productUrl,options)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.